# Как написать такую шаблонную функцию?

Tags: c++, c++11

Не пойму как в С++11 написать такую хотелку:

```
tempalte<class Signature>
struct Object
{
    typedef std::function<Signature> CallbackFunction;

    void registerCallback(const CallbackFunction&);
};

template<class T, ?????>
typedef T::Signature createCallback(T& obj, int id)
{
    void * addr = &obj;
    return [addr, id](??????) { std::cout << addr << id; };
}
```

Идея в том, что зная тип сингануры, сгенерировать лямбду, которой пофиг на  аргументы и она делает что-то простое.

Пример использования:

```
Object<void()> obj1;
obj1.registerCallback(createCallback(obj1, 42));

Object<int(A1, A2*, const A3&)> obj2;
obj2.registerCallback(createCallback(obj2, 777));
```

Comment: Извините, не могли бы Вы сформулировать практическую задачу, которая бы решалась использованием данного механизма?

Comment: @isnullxbh В моем случае есть куча сигналов с разной сигнатурой, я хочу регистрировать фак их срабатывания, для любого сигнала тело слота(callback) это выставление флажка в "1", мне лень каждый раз прописывать полную сигнатуру для каждого слота.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename TSignature> struct
Object
{
    using
    CallbackFunction = ::std::function<TSignature>;

    void
    registerCallback(const CallbackFunction &) {}
};

template<typename TResult> auto
makeResult(void) -> TResult
{
    return(TResult{});
}

template<> auto
makeResult<void>(void) -> void
{
    return;
}

template<typename TSignature> class
t_CallbackWrapper;

template<typename... TArgs, typename TResult> class
t_CallbackWrapper<TResult (TArgs...)> final
{
    private: void * m_p_obj;
    private: int    m_id;

    public: explicit
    t_CallbackWrapper(void * const p_obj, int const id): m_p_obj{p_obj}, m_id{id} {}

    public: auto
    operator ()(TArgs...) const -> TResult
    {
        ::std::cout << m_p_obj << m_id;
        return(makeResult<TResult>());
    }
};

template<typename TSignature> auto
makeCallback(Object<TSignature> & obj, int id) -> typename Object<TSignature>::CallbackFunction
{
    return
    (
        typename Object<TSignature>::CallbackFunction
        {
            t_CallbackWrapper<TSignature>{::std::addressof(obj), id}
        }
    );
}

int main()
{
    Object<void (void)> obj1;
    obj1.registerCallback(makeCallback(obj1, 42));

    Object<int (float, int *, const double &)> obj2;
    obj2.registerCallback(makeCallback(obj2, 777));

    ::std::cout.flush();
    return(0);
}
```

[Запустить в онлайн компиляторе](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sljK6G4ZwNaxvXek)

Comment: Спасибо, друг! То что надо, завелось сразу.

Comment: @ffk вроде бы Вы хотели лямбду. А тут её нет.

Comment: @alexolut Хотел. И зациклился на ней, а про функтор совсем забыл, а он решает мою проблему.